# Sound on collision

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine, game-engine

Can please someone format the code for me?

my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ScorePoint : MonoBehaviour 
{

    private AudioSource audioSource;
    public AudioClip Scored;

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider) 
    {

        if(collider.tag == "Player") 
        {
            audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
            audioSource.clip = Scored;
            audioSource.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

This code only works when the collider is **Is Trigger**.

Comment: Yes because it is the purpose of OnTriggerEnter, use OnCollisionEnter instead. But then this code only works when the collider is not IsTrigger.

Comment: Doesn't works for me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make it work with a collider not set as a trigger you should use `OnCollisionEnter2d` instead. Make sure to change the parameter from `Collider2d` to `Collision2d`.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ScorePoint : MonoBehaviour
{
    private AudioSource audioSource;
    public AudioClip Scored;

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
            audioSource.clip = Scored;
            audioSource.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

**OnTriggerEnter2d**

> Sent when another object enters a trigger collider attached to this object (2D physics only).

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html

**OnCollisionEnter2d**

> Sent when an incoming collider makes contact with this object's collider (2D physics only).

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html

Comment: Thanks.. but i get an error: **'UnityEngine.Collision2D' enthält keine Definition für 'gameobject'...** or in english **UnityEngine.Collision2D' contains no definition for'gameobject'...**

Comment: Did you change from collider to collision? See parameter difference in the code example.

Comment: My bad. It should be `collision.gameObject.tag`. Edited my answer as well.